# Have different colorbox overlay widths for certain viewport widths.

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, colorbox

So far my Colorbox ajax overlay window behaves and resizes well. When i resize the browser window, the percentages of the specified overlay extends are kept. I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax").colorbox({
        opacity:"0",  
        fixed:"true", 
        width:"65%",
        height:"97%",
    });
});
var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function(){
    if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('#cboxOverlay').is(':visible')) {
            $.colorbox.load(true);
        }
    }, 300)
});
```

The only problem i have left, is it possible to have different overlay extends for different viewport sizes e.g. a width of 95% for small viewports and a width of 65% for desktop viewports? Is it possible to accomplish something like that within Colorbox already or do i need something like jresond ( https://github.com/ten1seven/jRespond ) or is there an even more elegant solution? Best regards Ralf